# Hand Masterpassword to keepassxc-cli (or retrieve entry from keepassxc by vba)

Tags: vba, keepass

I tried a lot with the [keepassxc-cli manpage](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/blob/master/docs/man/keepassxc-cli.1.adoc) but was not able to solve my seemingly simple task. I couldn't find real examples as well.

I want to invoke keepass-cli from a vba-script (I have reasons ;-) ) and retrieve a username/password (can be in two steps) to use in a script. I can copy the password on the shell when typing:

```
$ keepassxc-cli clip "path\to\db" "db entry name"
```

Then I am prompted to type in my master password.
However I would like to keep the user from the cli and rather have an input in my original script so the user can type the master password there and the password is handed over seamlessly.

In short I am looking to a way to enter something along the lines

```
$ keepassxc-cli clip "path\to\db" "db entry name" -master "my secret master password"
```

NB: keepassxc has the option `--pw-stdin` which keepassxc-cli seems to be missing. (Then I could use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1210421))
Security level overall is quite low, however I don't want to put a database pw (for read access) verbatim into the script (as it is done by my predecessor), and in a company environment I cannot install plugins for keepassxc or similar.

Any pointers to some examples of keepass-cli examples are also very much appreciated.

Comment: Where/how are you prompted for a password? (console, inputbox, window etc)

Comment: When I enter the first command in the question above, I have to enter the db-password, as `--pw-stdin` isn't recognized from keepass-cli.
The ideal solution would be: I have the user being asked for a password to the keepass-db, the script does commands and the pw to the db I want to connect to from the script is passed to the script at runtime. (edited question to make this more clear (hopefully ;-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post is tagged with VBA, and your answer looks like a linux shell?

I couldn't get that to work using CMD, invalid credentials errors etc. (although I didn't try all that hard)

Powershell handles it just fine though.

Assumed you wanted VBA, the paths to the cli and database would need to be changed.

```
Sub ClipPassword(Name As String, Master As String)
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -Noninteractive -NoProfile -Command " & Chr(34) & Chr(39) & Master & Chr(39) & " | &" & Chr(39) & "C:\Path\To\KeePassXC-2.7.4-Win64\keepassxc-cli.exe" & Chr(39) & " clip " & Chr(39) & "C:\Path\To\Passwords.kdbx" & Chr(39) & " " & Name & Chr(34)
End Sub
```

The command run in powershell is essentially the same as your answer

```
"masterpassword" | &keepasxc-cli clip "database" account
```

Comment: I can rely on a linux shell, as we also have git for windows (that comes with a linux(-like ?) shell).
Your answer fulfils all my dreams and is more elegant for other's peoples environments I guess. So thanks a lot! The vba-part I wanted to figure out later ;-)
I didn't hope for an answer anymore, since I had received votes to close and a downvote (I did my best to edit the question afterwards) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Reading [this issue on keepassxc's github](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/6752) let me realise that [using `echo`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1210421) also helps here:

```
$ echo notsosecretpassword | keepassxc-cli clip "path\to\db" "db entry name"
```